# TortoiseSVN/Subversion Revision numbers...Altenate program?

Tags: version-control, revisions

I asked this question (below) a week ago and got the answer I was looking for, BUT, What program would work if I want the configuration management program to up a file to the next revision (by one unit) ONLY if it is edited. I understand the subversion does not do it that way, BUT what program will?

---

I am fairly new to Subversion/TortoiseSVN and I want to know if there is a way to prevent Subversion from skipping revision numbers on files so that I can track the amount of time a file is changed based on it's revision number:

Example: I have A.txt, B.txt, and C.txt Revision 1: (added the files to repository) A.txt :1 B.txt :1 C.txt :1

Revision 2: (edited files: A.txt and B.txt) A.txt :2 B.txt :2 C.txt :1

Revision 3: (edited files: A.txt and C.txt) A.txt :3 B.txt :2 C.txt :3 <---------I want this "3" to be a 2****

** I made one change to C.txt and I want the revision number to increase one time (not skip 2 and go straight to 3). I understand why Subversion/TortoiseSVN does it this way and how to follow it, but for the project I am working on, I want to do this a different way. I have read everywhere and can't seem to find anyone else with this issue. Any suggestions?

---

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, CVS keeps track of version numbers individually for every single file. So if you change file B and commit your changes to the repository, file A and C are not affected at all.

The version system is a bit different from Subversion though. Where SVN uses numbers from 1 to N, CVS numbers starts at 1.1, and the second digit is incremented with each commit (becoming 1.2, 1.3, and so on).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want to track revision numbers on a file-by-file basis.  That's a fairly outmoded concept, which is why more modern SCM packages don't support it.  On the other hand, that **is** the way that [CVS](http://www.nongnu.org/cvs/) works, so if that's what you feel you need, then go have a look at it.